# Excel comparing and filtering

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, vba

Quite a complicated VBA problem this time.

I have an excel workbook with two sheets; Data and Analyse.

The data sheet contains a column (T) with names and a column with results (Y).
The analyse sheet contains a cell with a name (B1).

I want to search the data sheet column T for the column name on the analyse sheet B1 cell. After identifying the cells with similar value, I need to output the contents of the corresponding results column. The results column has three possible values; 1, 2 or 3. I want display the total occurence of each possibility.

Tried Macro's and Vlookup, however get into trouble when trying to get the value of the result column :(

Looking forward to your responses!

Regards,

Pranav

Comment: "Similar" means what, exactly?

Comment: Need more information. Is the name in cell B1 a *column* name or a value that has a match in column T?  Will the name in B1 have multiple matches in column T? Do you want the analysis sheet to show a count of the number of occurences of 1, 2, and 3 for the names that match B1? Have you considered a pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a pivot table with the names in column T as the row value, and the values in column Y as the column value, and the "count of Y" as the value in the table, then you can look up the count of any number with a VLOOKUP into this table.  Simple example:

```
Count of number number          
name            1    2   3  Grand Total
a                   1    2   1   4
b                   3    3   2   8
d                   2    3   1   6
f                   3    6   2  11
g                   4    3   2   9
h                   1    3   1   5
j                   1    3   2   6
v                   1    1   1   3
Grand Total        16   24  12  52
```

As you can see, it would be easy to do a VLOOKUP into this table and get your answer. With a tip of the hat to @chuff who suggested something like this in a comment.

Comment: @Tim: Similar means an exact match.

Comment: @Chuff: The name in Cell B1 is a value that has a match with the values in column T. There will be multiple matches with only one number in column Y (1, 2 or 3). Although a Pivot table can work, it doesn't solve the problem, since I am searching from another sheet and need the results displayed there.

Comment: @babu: as long as you do the VLOOKUP on the sheet where you want the result, you will see the result there. You create the pivot table on a sheet of its own, and name the range (four columns wide, including only the rows with the names - not the column headings, and not the totals) "pivot1": then on the result sheet you write `=VLOOKUP(B1, pivot1, 2)` to get the count of ones. Repeat with the numbers 3 and 4 in the last parameter to get count of twos and threes.

Answer (score 0):

if you have Excel 2007 or later, then you can use `COUNTIFS`

for your example, I would put `=COUNTIFS(T:T,B1,Y:Y,1)` and change the 1 to 2 and 3 for the other columns

If you have Excel 2003 or before, then you would need to use `SUMPRODUCT` to get the same result, and would also have to define the ranges with a specific range, rather than reference the whole column.
e.g. `=SUMPRODUCT(--(T1:T300=B1),--(Y1:Y300=1))`